# How to share Spark RDD between 2 Spark contexts?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have an RMI cluster. Each RMI server has a Spark context.
Is there any way to share an RDD between different Spark contexts?

Answer (score 15):

As already stated by Daniel Darabos it is not possible. Every distributed object in Spark is bounded to specific context which has been used to create it (`SparkContext` in case of RDD, `SQLContext` in case of `DataFrame` dataset). If you want share objects between applications you have to use shared contexts (see for example [`spark-jobserver`](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/), [Livy](http://livy.io/), or [Apache Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.apache.org/)). Since `RDD` or `DataFrame` is just a small local object there is really not much to share.

Sharing data is a completely different problem. You can use specialized in memory cache ([Apache Ignite](https://ignite.apache.org/features/igniterdd.html)) or distributed in memory file systems (like [Alluxio](http://www.alluxio.org/) - former Tachyon) to minimize the latency when switching between application but you cannot really avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

No, an RDD is tied to a single `SparkContext`. The general idea is that you have a Spark cluster and one driver program that tells the cluster what to do. This driver would have the `SparkContext` and kick off operations on the RDDs.

If you want to just move an RDD from one driver program to another, the solution is to write it to disk (S3/HDFS/...) in the first driver and load it from disk in the other driver.

Answer (score 2):

You cant natively, in my understanding, RDD is not data, but a way to create data via transformations/filters from original data.

Another idea, is to share the final data instead. So, you will store the RDD in a data-store, such as :
- HDFS (a parquet file etc..)
- Elasticsearch
- Apache Ignite (in-memory)

I think you will love Apache Ignite: https://ignite.apache.org/features/igniterdd.html

> Apache Ignite provides an implementation of Spark RDD abstraction
>   which allows to easily share state in memory across multiple Spark
>   jobs, either within the same application or between different Spark
>   applications.
>
> IgniteRDD is implemented is as a view over a distributed Ignite cache,
>   which may be deployed either within the Spark job executing process,
>   or on a Spark worker, or in its own cluster.

(I let you dig their documentation to find what you are looking for.)