# Can output of Spark job used as input for another Spark job?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, real-time, spark-streaming, pyspark

I want to use output of one Spark job as input data for other Spark Job. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share Spark RDD between 2 Spark contexts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27917784/how-to-share-spark-rdd-between-2-spark-contexts)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As long as the output is stored somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

What separates these two jobs? You could just re-use the RDD from job #1 at job #2, alternatively (as already mentioned) you need to store it somewhere and read it from there at the beginning of job #2.